# Новый путь к скрипту nodejs socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

По умолчанию скрипты у меня ставятся в папке

> /root/script-server.js.

А я поставил тут

> /var/www/****/data/nodeserver/message.js

Два вопроса:
Как сделать что бы новый путь стал по умолчанию?
Почему выходит ошибка

> cannot fint module 'socket.io'

когда ставлю новый путь. Что `socket.io` не нравится?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй прописать в консоли linux:

```
export NODE_PATH /var/www/****/data/nodeserver
```

перед запуском твоего приложения

Comment: bash export not a valid identifier